# Why we need autocomplete plugin for Vim since we have omni completion?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, neocomplete

I am playing with vim currently and trying to configure it for a good editor for Java. When I configure the auto-completion feature for java, I was recommended to install plugins such as neocomplete or delplete.
But the default auto-completion like omni works just fine if you find the right source for omni-completion plugin such as vim-javacomplete2.

So why do we need such plugin like neocomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable reason you were recommended to use the `delplete` plugin is that it performs its autocompletion actions *asynchronously*. This can be a great benefit over native Vim autocompletion, which I believe still performs those actions synchronously.

The benefit lies in the case where the action to complete is long & slow: an asynchronous task will allow for other tasks to run alongside it while it works, while a synchronous task will block other tasks and make them wait for it to finish. Having "asynchronicity" will provide a smoother experience and shorter overall wait times.

Autocompletion tasks definitely have the capacity to be slower, but if you don't notice any slowdowns there's no pressing reason to switch to `delplete` if you don't want to.